# Where could I find the program logic of contract in the blockchain of ethereum in Mix?

Tags: blockchain, contract-debugging, mix, ide

[image]

I am trying the tutorial scenario of Mix (https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Mix:-The-DApp-IDE) for the first time and have a question here.

After I deployed the rating contract, where could I find the program logic on the blocks in the scenario window? and How could I get the native data of blockchain in Mix? 
Because I would like to find out how are the data and contracts stored in the blockchain. For example,if I "use" the contract with a value as input, which part would be added in the blockchain? the value itself? or a whole contract with the newly input value? or the ID of contract/transaction with the newly input value?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The contract and state are stored in a patricia merkle tree. 
https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Patricia-Tree.

In Mix this is stored in /tmp/mixdebug .

if you deploy a new contract (with one input parameter in the constructor), 
the code will be stored in the blockchain. If the input param is set to a global variable, it will be stored as well.

Then you can call "any" functions of this contract. The code will not be redeployed.